# Sending method parameters to action filter through the constructor

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.1

I'm building a website in ASP.NET Core and I just started setting up some filters to control the access to certain methods, and one of the criteria for some methods is the Referer header of the request.

I'd like to send the valid URL for the Referer to the action filter as an argument through the constructor.

I created the following filter:

```
public class RefererFilter : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    private List<string> referers;

    public RefererFilter(params string[] _referers)
    {
        referers = new List<string>(_referers);
    }

    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
    {
        bool valid = false;

        foreach (string referer in referers)
        {
            if (context.HttpContext.Request.Headers["Referer"].ToString() == ("https://" + context.HttpContext.Request.Host.Value + referer))
            {
                valid = true;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (!valid)
            context.Result = new StatusCodeResult(403);

        base.OnActionExecuting(context);
    }
}
```

And I'd like to use it like this:

```
[RefererFilter("/Users/ChangePassword/" + id)]
public IActionResult PasswordChanged(int id)
{
    return View();
}
```

The problem is that the variable "id" doesn't exist in the filter call.

I know there are other ways to do this by getting the attributes from inside the action filter by knowing their name in the method, but that would force me to create various filters because URLs don't all follow the same structure.

Is there any way this can be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Then just let the filter know the name of the action parameter. That what's the only thing the filter need to know.

Do you notice that the HttpGetAttribute also do this, by passing the parameter name

```
        [HttpGet("{id}")]
        public string Get(int id)
        {
```

And remember that curly braces are not valid in URIs (see RFC 3986). That's why it is safe for us to use it as a symbol that will be replaced later with the action parameter value. So you can make the url template become like this,

```
    [RefererFilter("/Users/ChangePassword/{id}")]
    public IActionResult PasswordChanged(int id)
    {
        return View();
    }

    [RefererFilter("/Users/EditUser/{id}/UserEmail/{email}")]
    public IActionResult EditUser(int id, string email)
    {
        return View();
    }
```

Then in the RefererFilter you will need to parse the value of the action parameter in OnActionExecuting method, could be like the following,

```
    public class RefererFilter : ActionFilterAttribute
    {
        private List<string> referers;

        public RefererFilter(params string[] _referers)
        {
            referers = new List<string>(_referers);
        }

        public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
        {
            bool valid = false;

            foreach (string referer in referers)
            {
                string r = referer;
                foreach(var arg in context.ActionArguments)
                {
                    r = r.Replace($"{{{arg.Key}}}", arg.Value.ToString());
                }

                if (context.HttpContext.Request.Headers["Referer"].ToString() == $"https://{context.HttpContext.Request.Host.Value}{r}")
                {
                    valid = true;
                    break;
                }
            }

            if (!valid)
                context.Result = new StatusCodeResult(403);

            base.OnActionExecuting(context);
        }
    }
```

Comment: I had already thought of something like this, but had no idea what characters I could use to identify the parameter names. Thanks, that will have to do!